# Infant visa online questionaire

Tags: visas, children

My sister is applying for a UK tourist visa for her 9 month old baby. What should she write in columns like employment, daily expenditure and gross expenditure?

Answer (score 3):

Just the common sense answers they’d expect. Don’t worry and don’t overthink. Employment none. Expenditure 1 pound